# Rust automatic type inference on trait implementation

Tags: rust

I don't really understand what is the issue with my code below. Not clearly anyways. I used to parameterize Toto with a lifetime but I figured I'd give lifetime inference a shot. The issue seems to be with the reference to self.I get the compiler error:

```
embedded_lifetimes.rs:11:5: 11:10 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements
embedded_lifetimes.rs:11     slice
                         ^~~~~
embedded_lifetimes.rs:10:3: 12:4 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn klax<'a>(&'a self, slice: &'a [String]) -> &[String]
embedded_lifetimes.rs:10   fn klax(&self, slice: &[String]) -> &[String] {
embedded_lifetimes.rs:11     slice
embedded_lifetimes.rs:12   }
```

For the following code:

```
#![feature(slicing_syntax)]

trait Toto {
  fn klax(&self, &[String]) -> &[String];
}

struct Tata;

impl Toto for Tata {
  fn klax(&self, slice: &[String]) -> &[String] {
    slice
  }
}

fn main() {
  let t = Tata;
  t.klax(&["myello".to_string()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your trait back to:

```rust
trait Toto<'a> {
    fn klax(&self, &'a [String]) -> &'a [String];
}
```

[As I understand it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/wiki/Doc-detailed-release-notes#examples), if you leave off all the lifetimes, lifetime elision will yield:

```rust
trait Toto<'a> {
    fn klax(&'a self, &[String]) -> &'a [String];
}
```

That is, you return a slice of `String`s that belong to the *object*. However, you want the result to come from the *input*, which isn't what the default rules will give.

**Edit**

The suggested change to

```rust
fn klax<'a>(&'a self, slice: &'a [String]) -> &[String]
```

Says that your *object* and the *input* have the same lifetime. The result lifetime would also be `'a` (by the elision rules), and so returning the input would fit the lifetime. If this made sense for your case and you were to make this change, you'd get the error:

```
method `klax` has an incompatible type for trait: expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter
```

Because now your trait and implementation of that trait no longer match.

Comment: Yeah all right I had tried that and experienced that error: parameterizing the implementation of klax but not the trait. Your explanation on the inference answers my question. Thanks!